# Splitting response at a certain point

Tags: php, .net, vb.net

I had a question earlier involving php and mysql on this same project,

This is .net, Im trying to read the source of my php response, and stop after a certain character or phrase, in which mine is `<br />`

I Tried google, and got no luck, Im hoping somebody here can save me!

here is my current code.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles     Button1.Click
        Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest =    System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://mywebsite/db.php?hwid=" + TextBox1.Text)
        Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim name As String = sr.ReadToEnd
        If name = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("HWID Not Activated!", "Error: Invalid HWID")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome, " + name)
            Me.Hide()
            Form1.Show()
        End If
    End Sub
```

I Want to stop reading everything after the source at `<br />`

Comment: Is the `If` block for checking the value of `name` necessary to show?  If it's important, then you must have omitted something important because the code doesn't show where `name` comes from or how it gets set.

Comment: Name is what my php file is responding with, im having the program submit the hwid that its grabbing from the client, to the php file, and reading the php files response, in which i have declared here as name. i added `if name = "" Then` because, if there is no hwid, it will show up blank. but its not showing up blank to the application, because its reading the source, thats why I want it to stop reading after that `<br />` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find where the "<br />" is and get the string before that:

```
Dim s = "Andrew<br />Morton"
Dim brIndex = s.IndexOf("<br />")
Dim myName As String = ""
If brIndex >= 0 Then
    myName = s.Substring(0, brIndex)
End If
Console.WriteLine(myName)
' outputs: Andrew
```

Also, you need to call .Close() on the HttpWebResponse.

And, the string concatenation operator in VB.NET is "&", not "+".

Comment: Sorry for the late response trying this now.